NavigationView extra spacing
In the code below you can see the ChestView on my workout app, in which I want to display Chest workouts after selecting the Chest Workouts option on the previous NavigationStack page. My goal is to get rid of the extra blank spacing it adds. I want to have the spacing removed but the title and the back button still there. I am not sure how to do it. I have tried .navigationBarHidden(true) and it does the job but completely hides the back button as well, this is not my goal. Does anyone have a simple solution to this?

import SwiftUI

struct ChestView: View {
    //CREATE AN ARRAY FOR THE VIDEOS
    var videos: [Video] = VideoList.chest
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            List(videos, id: \.id) { video in
                
                
                HStack{
                    Image(video.imageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 125, height: 70)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .padding(.vertical, 4)
                    
                    Text(video.title)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
                        .fontDesign(.serif)
                        .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    NavigationLink (
                        destination: ExerciseDetailView(video: video),
                        label: {
                        })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Chest Workouts:")
        }
        
        
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    ChestView()
}

As seen above I have tried the .navigationBarHidden(true) fix before but it does not work how I am envisioning it.

You only need 1 NavigationView/Stack at the top of your app, for the entire app. TabViews and sheets are exceptions.
